# c# : when can I know that webbrowser controller Url changed to a specific url?

Tags: c#, url, browser

My c# application has a web browser to navigate to websites

I need to know if the user wants to go a specific URL

The problem is that the user does not always use the URL in the text-box for navigation, they may enter the site through a referral link (like a search engine result)

Is there any way to do a specific operation only when web browser navigates to a specific URL ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried subscribing for the [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) event? This event will be triggered everytime the browser changes url.

Comment: thanks, but I will use Navigated event , as in Navigating event the url value of webbrowser is the old one; but in Navigating event the url value is the new one